# MS Access Linked Table Not Updating New Fields

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access Database which has a Linked Table called "Combined" that is from a text file. I have added a new field to the Txt File but this new field is not showing in the Access Table "Combined". I have right-clicked on the "Combined" table in Access and opened up the Linked Table Manager and refreshed the link and it is still not showing. When I go through the process of Linking the Data Source(.txt file) to a new table "Combined2" it shows the new field. I am not sure what I can do to remedy this. I have tried to just create a new linked file and overwrite the table name "Combined" with the linked file but then it makes it so my queries no longer function that were linked to the "Combined" table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop linked table in Access and create it again. Just refreshing the link in linked tables manager is not enough in case of text files because it creates import specification, which is specific for file format.

Comment: I have done this, but then I will have to add this to every query within the database that uses this table. Over 135. I have also tried to link the table again and overwrite the name of the currently used file, but then the queries loose the reference of the table and say that it is missing when I open the query.

Comment: Before doing this go to Options -> Current Database and uncheck Track Name Autocorrect option. Also I highly recommend to do not use linked tables with text source in queries. Import the data from file to normal table and use it.